# Regex match part of word

Tags: java, regex

I want to match part of a word and this works if the length of the word in the pattern is less than the string the I am matching, example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Stude");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Student");

System.out.println(m.find())
```

outputs true. However if the length of the word is larger then it returns false, example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Studentsrter");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Student");

System.out.println(m.find())
```

So how can I match only part of the word?

Comment: Is there a minimum that must match? Eg, would `"S"` be considered a match to `"Studentsrter"`?

Comment: Maybe `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Student\w*");`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern `(?i).*(student).*`, like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*(student).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("asaStudentstrtr");
```

Where:

`(?i)` makes it caseinsensitive

`.*` means 0 or more any characters

and `(student)` is the concrete group of characters you want to find

For your purposes, you can delete `(?i)` to make it case sensitive or `.*` in the beginning or at the end of the pattern, to determine the position of required word in the string.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Student).*");
```

Will match Student followed by anything else.